# Hosting IRC server on Mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, irc

Not having found any, I stumbled upon this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19411/how-do-i-set-up-an-irc-server-on-os-x-for-my-local-network) that explains how to install ngIRCd with homebrew and I decided to give it a try.

First off I ran the ruby script and successfully installed HomeBrew: it did however return an error about its sbin not being in my path. Therefore I ran `homebrew doctor` and it returned the following error:

```
Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your path.
Consider amending your PATH variable so it contains:
  /usr/local/sbin
```

I found a post that suggested editing the /etc/paths file so that the `/usr/local/bin` line came before the `/usr/bin` line: I edited the file by SFTPing into my server and now its contents are:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

However the error persisted. I found this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175773/echo-path-doesnt-match-bash-profile) and tried entering `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"` in the terminal and tested the HomeBrew config again and this time it reported no errors.

Happy of the results I went on to install ngIRCd following the first post. I entered `brew install ngircd` and it did all of its magic without reporting any errors. I then went on with step two and pasted the `vi ~/.bash_profile` command in the terminal window but a series of lines with a `$` sign at the beginning appeared and I couldn't get it to work. I closed the window, opened a new one, and typed in `ngircd` to start the server and it gave me a

```
bash: command not found
```

error.

However entering the `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"` command once again in the new window followed by the `ngircd` command didn't return any errors. Therefore I went on and customized the ngIRCd config file in /usr/local/Cellar/ngircd/20.1/etc/ngircd.conf and tried logging into the server via Adium, only to get an `Access denied: bad password` error... I even restored the original .conf file to no avail. And of course there's the problem that I have to enter the `export PATH` command every single time I log into terminal. What am I doing wrong? I'd be happy to explore completely different solutions of course if there's some kind of guide i can follow!

I think this is how it went, but I might have missed or forgotten a few details. I hope this makes sense to someone among you out there xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally found the solution. Apparently it was very simple and straightforward.

I gave the aforementioned post a second look and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14175801/2368095) proved to be the key. I looked up how to create a `.bash_profile` file and found this [tutorial](http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/creating-bashprofile-your-mac) to be very helpful. After creating the file I pasted in the text from the answer linked above (`export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin"`) with no brackets or spaces before or after and saved the file. As indicated in the same answer I then ran `source ~/.bash_profile` in the terminal and I restarted just to be on the safe side. After reboot I ran `brew doctor` once again this time finding it to be working properly reporting no errors. I then uninstalled ngircd via homebrew and reinstalled it following the post linked above in my original question. I started up ngircd and the `Access denied` error was gone.

I hope this helps someone out there.

Thanks everybody anyway: I love the community and I look forward to be part of it in the future :)